# How to style a Javascript snippet

Tags: javascript, stylesheet, css

I want to embed this Javascript snippet (webform from AWeber) into my website:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://forms.aweber.com/form/49/522310949.js"></script>`

My site uses the style `p { line-height: 1.5em; }`. Unfortunately this is also applied to the Javascript snippet and makes it look stupid.

How can I tell the Javascript snippet to use a line-height of 1em instead of 1.5em?

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
<p style="line-height: 1em;">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://forms.aweber.com/form/49/522310949.js"   
</script>
</p>
```

I also considered using Javascript (`document.getElementById('p').style.lineHeight = '1 em';`) to change the CSS, but as I understand Javascript modifies the whole website and not only one element...

Can you please help?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: How does the HTML that the JS adds to your website look like? (Consider making an example on something like [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so we could actually see the problem.)

Comment: Your SCRIPT element is at this point a black box - it's not possible to answer your question until you explain what that script does.

Comment: Thanks. It's solved now (see comments below).
The reason why you don't see the webform now is that I just switched it from an inline form to a lightbox (which pops up only after 10 minutes).

Answer (score 1):

Putting the form inside a `<p>` does not make sense, as `<p>` cannot contain block-level elements. Use a `<div>` instead:

```
<div style='line-height: 1em;'>
  <script src = " ... "></script>
</div>
```

As @Max implicitly noted, it'd be "nicer" to add CSS to style the content.

You can use Firebug or the Chrome/Safari developer tools to examine the styles of "live" page elements. That can help you figure out the reasons that particular elements look a particular way, and it also lets you play around with alterations to the styles.

*edit* maybe something like:

```
div.af-form p { line-height: 1em; }
```

Comment: I tried this before but it didn't solve the issue. 
The part in the webform which uses `<p>` has still 1.5em instead of 1em.
Any other ideas?

Comment: Override that style with a more-specific CSS rule of your own.

Comment: Thank you so much!
`div.af-form p { line-height: 1em; }` works fine!! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
div.af-form {
    line-height: 1em;
}
```

In case you need more styling, I see that your generated block also uses these styles: `af-header`, `af-body`, `af-footer`, `af-element` and `af-textWrap`.

However, if you need a more universal solution, refer to @Pointy's answer.

Comment: Thank you so much!
`div.af-form p { line-height: 1em; }` works fine!! :)